# Multiplication for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can I prove following theorem

> $$(\lambda A)*B =A(\lambda B)=\lambda (A*B)$$
>   like this?

**My proof of the first equal sign**

We know that an easier notation for a generell matris, e.g A, is
$$A= \ (a_{ij})_{1<=i<=m, 1<=j<=n}$$
So, we can rewrite the LHS as
$$(\lambda A)*B= (\lambda \ (a_{ij})_{1<=i<=m, 1<=j<=n})*(b_{kl})_{1<=k<=n, 1<=l<=p}$$
and by the commutative rule and associative rule for integer numbers we get that
$$ (\lambda \ a_{ij})b_{kl}=(\ a_{ij}b\lambda) b_{kl} = \ a_{ij}(\lambda b_{kl})$$ 
which gives us

$$(\lambda \ (a_{ij})_{1<=i<=m, 1<=j<=n})*(b_{kl})_{1<=k<=n, 1<=l<=p}=\ (a_{ij})_{1<=i<=m, 1<=j<=n}*(\lambda b_{kl})_{1<=k<=n, 1<=l<=p}=\ (a_{ij})_{1<=i<=m, 1<=j<=n}*(\lambda ( b_{kl})_{1<=k<=n, 1<=l<=p}) = A*(\lambda B)$$

hence
$$(\lambda A)*B =A(\lambda B)$$

Is this enough for a proof, or is this even close for a proof? Doing some repitions (haven't worked with matrices in 7 months now so I have forgot the most).

I know that I can proove this by showing that an element in LFH is equal to an element in RHS for all i and j, but the proof above was my first I tried with and I am wondering if it were right.

At last, i wounder if i can use same method as above to prove

> $$(A+B)*C=A*C+B*C$$

Comment: Consider using \le to get $\le$

Comment: thanks. First time using math stack so i can't all "commands" :)

Comment: We just use ordinary LaTeX commands: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: As vadim123 points out, your attempt to a proof actually does nothing else than restating the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of this exercise is to prove that the following two operations are associative:

1. Multiplying each entry of a matrix by a scalar.
2. Multiplying two matrices.

Essential to any proof is the definition of matrix multiplication, which does not appear in the provided attempt.

$$(AB)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$$